# How to correctly understand TrueType cmap's subtable Format 4?

Tags: truetype

The following is the information, which the TrueType font format [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cmap#language) provides with regards to the fields of "Format 4: Segment mapping to delta values" subtable format, which may be used in `cmap` font table (the one used for mapping character codes to glyph indeces):

> ```
> Type  Name    Description
> 1. uint16     format  Format number is set to 4.
> 2. uint16     length  This is the length in bytes of the subtable.
> 3. uint16     language    For requirements on use of the language field, see “Use of the language field in 'cmap' subtables” in this document.
> 4. uint16     segCountX2  2 × segCount.
> 5. uint16     searchRange     2 × (2**floor(log2(segCount)))
> 6. uint16     entrySelector   log2(searchRange/2)
> 7. uint16     rangeShift  2 × segCount - searchRange
> 8. uint16     endCode[segCount]   End characterCode for each segment, last=0xFFFF.
> 9. uint16     reservedPad     Set to 0.
> 10. uint16    startCode[segCount]     Start character code for each segment.
> 11. int16     idDelta[segCount]   Delta for all character codes in segment.
> 12. uint16    idRangeOffset[segCount]     Offsets into glyphIdArray or 0
> 13. uint16    glyphIdArray[ ]     Glyph index array (arbitrary length)
> ```
>
> (Note: I numbered the fields as to allow referencing them)

Most fields, such as `1. format`, `2. length,`3. language`,`9. reservedPad` are trivial basic info and understood.

Other fields `4. segCountX2`, `5. searchRange`, `6 .entrySelector`, `7. rangeShift` I see as some odd way to have a precomputed values, but basically being only a redundant way to store the number of segments `segCount` (implicitly). Also those fields I have no major headache understanding.

Lastly there remain the fields that represent arrays. Per each segment there is a field `8. endCode`, `10. stadCode`, `11. idDelta` and `12. idRangeOffset` and there *might/might not* be even a field `13. glyphIdArray`. Those are the fields I still struggle to interprete correctly and which this question is about.

To allow for a most helpful answer allow me to sketch quickly my take on those fields:

- Working basically segment for segment, each segment maps characters codes from `startCode` to `endCode` to the indexes of the fonts glyphs (reflecting the order they appear in the `glyf` table).
- having the character code as input
- having the glyph index as output
- segment is determined by iterating through them checking that the input value is inside the range of `startCode` to `endCode`.
- with the segment found thus, the fields respective fields `idRangeOffset` and `idDelta` are determined as well.
- `idRangeOffset` conveys a special meaning
- case A) `idRangeOffset` being set to special value `0` means that the ouput can be
  calculated from the input value (character code) and the `idDelta`. (I think it is either `glyphId = inputCharCode + idDelta` or `glyphId = inputCharCode - idDelta` )
- case B) `idRangeOffset` being not `0` something different happens, which is part of what I seek an answer about here.

With respect to case B) the documentation states:

> If the idRangeOffset value for the segment is not 0, the mapping of
>   character codes relies on glyphIdArray. The character code offset from
>   startCode is added to the idRangeOffset value. This sum is used as an
>   offset from the current location within idRangeOffset itself to index
>   out the correct glyphIdArray value. This obscure indexing trick works
>   because glyphIdArray immediately follows idRangeOffset in the font
>   file. The C expression that yields the glyph index is:
>
> ```
> glyphId = *(idRangeOffset[i]/2
>             + (c - startCode[i])
>             + &idRangeOffset[i])
> ```

which I think provides a way to map a continuous input range (hence "segment") to a list of values stored in the field `glyphIdArray`, possibly as a way to provide output values that cannot be computed via idDelta, for being unordered/non-consecutive.  This at least is my read on that what was described as "obscure" in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Because `glyphIdArray[]` follows `idRangeOffset[]` in the TrueType file, the code segment in question

```
glyphId = *(&idRangeOffset[i]
         + idRangeOffset[i]/2
         + c - startCode[i])
```

points to the memory address of the desired position in `glyphIdArray[]`. To elaborate on why:

- `&idRangeOffset[i]` points to the memory address of `idRangeOffset[i]`
- moving forward `idRangeOffset[i]` bytes (or `idRangeOffset[i]/2` uint16's) brings you to the relevant section of `glyphIdArray[]`
- `c - startCode[i]` is the position in `glyphIdArray[]` that contains the desired ID value

From here, in the event that this ID is not zero, you will add `idDelta[i]` to obtain the glyph number corresponding to `c`.

It is important to point out `*(&idRangeOffset[i] + idRangeOffset[i]/2 + (c - startCode[i]))` is really pseudocode: you don't want a value stored in your program's memory, but rather *the memory address in the file*.

In a more modern language without pointers, the above code segment translates to:

```
glyphIndexArray[i - segCount + idRangeOffset[i]/2 + (c - startCode[i])]
```

The `&idRangeOffset[i]` in the original code segment has been replaced by `i - segCount` (where `segCount = segCountX2/2`). This is because the range offset (`idRangeOffset[i]/2`) is relative to the memory address `&idRangeOffset[i]`.

Comment: So, how do you compute the GlyphID in a modern language without pointers? Because C code is not super useful if you have python lists or JS arrays, instead of pointers to some memory location

Comment: (e,g given the known file position for the start of `idRangeOffset` "array", and segment `i`, how would one find the glyphid and `glyphIdArray` index?)

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your question as best as I could. The answer is there, but my explanation could use elaboration. PS: your primer on Bezier curves was incredibly useful to me, so it's both an honor and a very funny coincidence that you've replied to my answer!

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Also, fun fact: the primer itself was born out of font-related things back in 2011.